# Continuing query Powershell switch param

Tags: powershell, if-statement, parameters, switch-statement

I wanted to write a Powershell module that can read the information from all PCs in my domain. The script works as well at the moment, but I would like to make multiple selections possible for the "Switch" param. Example: "Get-BERPCinfoFilter - Disk -Serial -Processor". How do I have to adapt the "if" query for the "switch" parameters so that this is possible?
Thanks in advance.

```
function Get-BERPCinfoFilter {
     param(
        [switch]$Processor,
        [Switch]$Videocard,
        [Switch]$Disk,
        [Switch]$memory,
        [Switch]$Serial
    )
    
Write-Host Please wait...

#Search all PCs in Domain
$ADC = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase <#Ou from Domain#> | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 
#Get informations from this PCs
$Function = ForEach ($Computer in $ADC){
            $Computername = $Computer
             $Connection = Test-Connection $Computername -Count 1 -Quiet

                  if($Connection -match "True"){
                            Write-Host "$Computername is reachable!" -ForegroundColor Green
                             
                                #Processor
                            if($Processor -match "True"){
                                Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Computername -Class Win32_Processor | 
                                Select-Object -Property Name
                                }

                                #Videocard
                            if($Videocard -match "True"){
                                Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Computername -Class Win32_VideoController | 
                                Select-Object -Property Name,DriverVersion,@{Label="DriverDate";Expression={$_.DriverDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")}}
                                }

                                #Disk
                            if($Disk -match "True"){
                                Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Computername -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType=3" | 
                                Select-Object DeviceID, VolumeName, @{n="Size in GB";e={[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}}, @{n="FreeSpace in GB";e={[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}}  
                                }

                                #Memory
                            if($Memory -match "True"){
                                Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Computername -class Win32_Physicalmemory | 
                                Select-Object Devicelocator,@{n="Capacity in GB";e={[math]::truncate($_.capacity / 1GB)}}
                                }

                                #Serial
                            if($Serial -match "True"){
                                Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Computername -class win32_bios | 
                                Select-Object Serialnumber
                                }

                           }

                  if($Connection -match "False"){ 
                            Write-Host "$Computername is not reachable!" -ForegroundColor Red
                        }

            }

         $Pfad = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Result.csv"
         $Function | Export-Csv -Path $Pfad -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
         Write-Host "The result is saved at path: $Pfad" -ForegroundColor Yellow
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `switch` *statement* (*not* related to the `[switch]` parameter type, other than by name) over `$PSBoundParameters`:

```
function Get-BERPCinfoFilter {
    param(
        [string]$ComputerName,
        [switch]$Processor,
        [Switch]$Videocard,
        [Switch]$Disk,
        [Switch]$Memory,
        [Switch]$Serial
    )

    switch($PSBoundParameters.Keys){
        'Processor' { 
            Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Computername -Class Win32_Processor |
              Select-Object -Property Name
        }
        'Videocard' { 
           # code to fetch GPU info
        }
        'Disk' { 
           # code to fetch disk info
        }
        'Memory' { 
           # code to fetch memory info
        }
        'Serial' { 
           # code to fetch serial
        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice that I've deliberately left out the part where you query Active Directory for all the computers.

By refactoring the function to only query *one* computer at a time, you can now re-use it with more flexibility. For your existing use case (querying *all* computers), you can still do:

```
$AllComputers = Get-ADComputer

$Details = foreach($Computer in $AllComputers){
    $Connection = Test-Connection $Computer.Name -Count 1 -Quiet
    if($Connection){
        Get-BERPCinfoFilter -ComputerName $Computer.Name -Processor -Disk -Whatever
    }
}

$Details |Select property,names |Export-Csv ...
```

... but now you can also be more selective with the computers you target (instead of always waiting for the function to query ALL machines):

```
# Much faster if we only need info on one or a few machines
$computer1Memory = Get-BERPCinfoFilter -ComputerName computer01 -Memory
```

Comment: And once you implement this, you can have multiple computers being returned at once by running as jobs... if you feel like it

Comment: I insert the switch case, but it can only output one property.

Comment: @KilianP. They're being output, you're just not seeing them because PowerShell's formatting subsystem only shows the properties found on the first item in the resulting collection. Try `$Details |Select *`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, "| Select *" only gets me the name and not the over properties.

Comment: @KilianP. Just to be clear, you replaced the `# code to fetch ...` comments in my sample with the actual code, right?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I posted a new answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is my new function with switch:

```
                $Function= switch($PSBoundParameters.Keys){      
                                #Processor
                            'Processor' {
                                Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Computername -Class Win32_Processor | 
                                Select-Object -Property Name
                                }

                                #Videocard
                            'Videocard' { 
                                #$os = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computername –Class Win32_OperatingSystem
                                Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Computername -Class Win32_VideoController | 
                                Select-Object -Property Name,DriverVersion,@{Label="DriverDate";Expression={$_.DriverDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")}}
                                }

                                #Disk
                            'Disk' {
                                Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Computername -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType=3" | 
                                Select-Object DeviceID, VolumeName, @{n="Size in GB";e={[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}}, @{n="FreeSpace in GB";e={[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}}  
                                }

                                #Memory
                            'Memory' { 
                                Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Computername -class Win32_Physicalmemory | 
                                Select-Object Devicelocator,@{n="Capacity in GB";e={[math]::truncate($_.capacity / 1GB)}}
                                }

                                #Serial
                            'Serial' {
                                Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $Computername -class win32_bios | 
                                Select-Object Serialnumber
                                }

                           }
$Function | select * | Export-Csv -Path $Pfad -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```